# show alert when textbox input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

I want to show an alert when the text box input of the first name is empty.

***Javascript Code***

```
<script>
    function validation() {
        var fname = document.getElementByID("fname").value;
        if ( fname== "")
            alert("Enter First Name");
    }
</script>
```

***HTML Code***

```
    <form>
        First name:
        <input type="text" id="fname">
        <br/><br/>
        <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="validation()">Submit</button>
        <button id="btnReset">Reset</button><br/>
        <button id="btnMenue"><a href= "index.php">Menue</a></button>
    </form>
```

I have tried related articles but they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: **getElementById** is spelled wrong. You have typed in your code ``getElementByID`` but it should be **getElementById**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementByID is not a function`, you have a type in your code:

`getElementByID` <- last letter is big in you code, should be small `getElementById`

working example

```js
function validation() {
  //                               big D, throws error 
  // var fname = document.getElementByID("fname").value;
     var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  console.log(fname);
  if (fname == "")
    alert("Enter First Name");
}
```

```html
<form>
  First name:
  <input type="text" id="fname"><br/><br/>

  <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="validation()">Submit</button>
  <button id="btnReset">Reset</button><br/>
  <button id="btnMenue"><a href= "index.php">Menue</a></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Two issues in your code:

1. `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`
2. You need to capture the event object and call `preventDefault` on it to stop the default behaviour that is stop form submission.

```js
function validation(e) {

  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value; // Typo here ID should be Id.
  if (fname == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Enter First Name");
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  First name:
  <input type="text" id="fname"><br/><br/>
  <button id="btnSubmit" onClick="validation(event)">Submit</button>
  <button id="btnReset">Reset</button><br/>
  <button id="btnMenue"><a href= "index.php">Menue</a></button>
</form>
```